# Use Solidify modifier

Tags: solidify-modifier

[image]

As you can see while using *Solidify* some faces appeared outside the mesh. I want them to be inside as here

[image]

Here's a drawing to illustrate what I want.

[image]

In green this is what I want. In the second color red is the original and the dark-red is effect of *Solidify*. I marked also with blue and green from which faces *Solidify* created others.

What I want to do is clamp these walls in mesh, so they cant go outside the mesh. In this case it's deleting those 2 triangles on the right. Can somebody share with me their solution?

If it isn't clear I'm soldifying inside mesh, not outside.

Comment: Have you checked for flipped normals?

Comment: yes I have chekced

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the Complex mode of the [Solidify modifier](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.93/modeling/modifiers/generate/solidify.html) which specifically states "This is a solidify algorithm which can handle every geometric situation to guarantee a manifold output geometry."   The simple mode is just adding a specified thickness to all surfaces, regardless of whether it then protrudes out another face.

[image]

Comment: I could have used this just the other day.

Comment: for me also worked setting thickness clamp, thx for answer it helped a lot :)