# Solidify not preserving the original surface

Tags: solidify-modifier

I am applying the solidify modifier to a surface I have. The surface represents a terrain with mountains. When I apply solidify in python the input surface appears to be modified, ie where the sharp edges are (think cones with acute angles). It kind of makes sense but I would really like to keep the original surface as it is, even if the thickness is not respected. Is there an option for this?

Here is the python code I use

```
solidify_modifier = obj.modifiers.new(name="Solidify", type='SOLIDIFY')
solidify_modifier.thickness = thickness  # Set the thickness value
solidify_modifier.offset = -1
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=solidify_modifier.name)
```

Some screenshots:

[image]

[image]

First picture is after solidifying, second is the actual surface. You can see some protusions on the front, which I assume come from the extension of the relief behind the edge.

The following image is the view with the edges and the normals

[image]

I also tried to use the complex algorithm instead but the results were actually worse somehow.

Comment: Hello. Could you share a screenshot of your setup ? Also please make sure all your normals are facing outwards otherwise the solidify will produce spiky artifacts

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by a screenshot of setup? I am doing everything via python. I can send an image of the obj file rendered by a viewer if it can help. I think your comment on normals makes sense. Is there a function I can use to check if they are facing outwards?

Comment: OK, I installed Blender and I am displaying the normals. They all look OK with the right orientation, so it might not be the issue.

Comment: A before / after screenshot showing off where the messed up angles problem appear would be enough I think. A wireframe shot of the object, too

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/238837/use-solidify-modifier?rq=1 ?

Comment: I updated the question with screenshots, let me know if you need more. I can also send you the initial surface file (.obj) if you want. I tried with complex solidify but it gave me worse results (more artifacts on the edges). I was also thinking another strategy would be to "clip" (if that exists) the solidified model with the original surface?